# How to split the polynomial .

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

How do I split  $x^2-5 $ in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ ? Since $0$ is a root I have $x $ as linear factor . How can I find the other linear factor ?

Comment: $x^2=x\times x$

Comment: -1 This really shows *very* little effort; there are only $4$ other candidates for the roots, and none of them are roots. Or you could have tried polynomial long division. Or simplified $x^2-5$ to $x^2$.

Comment: @Servaes: I'd say that this shows more effort than a lot more recent questions.

Comment: @user21820 Regardless of the quality of other questions, I find this one deeply subpar. But feel free to link some more questions to close.

Comment: @Servaes: Sure. You can find many [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1029455) (especially in the middle and bottom).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that $x^2-5 = x^2$, which is already factorised.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Vieta's formulas still work. The sum of the two roots equals the (negative of the) coefficient of the first degree term.